# How to send object for request in Laravel controller from Vue JS frontend by GET request?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have created a function in my controller that receives a request and does some calculations after that and stuff. Currently I am just showing the request array for checking:

```
public function check_availability(Request $request){
        dd($request->all());
        //other works to use this request values
         
    }
```

Now when I am sending a request to the route which hits this function using postman like this:
[image]

So it is working perfectly from postman. But the same request is returning blank request array when I am sending the request  from my vue js application.

```
var data= {
          "qty": 1000,
          "id": 1
        }
        var config = {
          method: 'get',
          url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/check_quantity',
          data: data
        };

        axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log("returned :", response)
          commit('set_products', payload);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log("this is error:",error);
        });
```

This is returning blank array! This is working when I am configuring the whole system in POST method. How can I solve this using get method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to pass data in `get` method you have to add them in [query params](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) like `?=foo=bar`

so your code should like like

```js
var data= {
  qty: 1000,
  id: 1
}
var config = {
  method: 'get',
  url:`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/check_quantity?qty=${data.qty}&id=${data.id}`,
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log("returned :", response)
  commit('set_products', payload);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log("this is error:",error);
});
```

Comment: So there is no way of sending body data with get method? I knew this parameter way, but wanted to use the body data way.

Comment: `body` and `params` is different  `post` request have body and get request have `params` to send data. it is `http` protocol's term. and postman also behind the seen doing this